# User specified file removal using remove function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm attempting to add the ability for players to be able to delete their save.txt files from the games folder

```
 remove("Saves/" + FileName + ".txt");
```

I tried to use the remove function which has worked well for me before, with the user entered FileName String in the middle but this gives me the error message 'error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::basic_string' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'|'

So after searching this I tried:

```
 const char * FileNames = FileName.c_str();
```

Turning filename into a char but now the compiler says I can't use the operands + or << to add the char

I'm now a little lost

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Since C++17, there is `<filesystem>` which might help with files handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+operator can concatenate two std::string or std::string and a **const char*** but it doesn't mean for two const char* or even when the left hand side variable is a const char*

use this code instead:

```
remove((std::string("Saves/") + FileName + ".txt").c_str())
```

now you are trying to concatenate a std::string to a const char* which is a valid operation in c++. and finally, you can get the const char* from a std::string using **.c_str()** which is always useful when dealing with lagacy codes that just accept const char* as their input parameters.

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem.  Since `FileName` is a `std::string`, the additions are fine.  The result is a `std::string` that cannot be passed to `remove`.

Comment: just use .c_str on std::string to get the const char* of the string. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

with `std::string FileName;`, it would be `remove(("Saves/" + FileName + ".txt").c_str())` as [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) expects `const char*`.